# How can I replace my CloudFront distribution with another without user downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

**Initial Setup**

- On AWS I have a Elastic Beanstalk (EB) server that serves pages.
- During any month for a particular request it will always serve the same data so I set up a Cloudfront distribution to better serve customers and reduce server hits.
- In Route53 have domain configured to point to Cloudfront distribution
- All customer access is via this domain

**Each Month**

- I deploy a new version of EB Server
- I then wanted to invalidate all pages within my CloudFront so that it would get newest data from EB Server.

But invalidation is slow and expensive so instead my plan was to just create a new Cloudfront distribution. then modify my Route53 domain to point to the new CloudFront, then once done delete the original CloudFront distribution.

The trouble is that CloudFront does not let you create a new distribution if you set an  **Alternate CName** that is already used by another distribution. So I cannot create my new distribution until I have disabled and then deleted the existing one, and then I have to deploy my new one, this takes ages and would be site would be down for that period.

My alternative is as follows

- Deploy new EB Server
- Point Route53 to Load balancer of new EB Server
- Disable CloudFront Distribution, and wait.
- Delete CloudFront Distribution, and wait.
- Create new CloudFront Distribution, and wait.
- Point Route 53 Domain to new CloudFront Distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't have to wait for the distribution to be deleted to reuse the cname.  I do something similar.

- create a new distribution that has identical settings as my current one, minus the cname settings
- remove the cname from the old distribution, save
- immediately add cname to new distribution
- update DNS to point to new distribution
- keep old distribution around until both are deployed
- disable and then delete, to clean up

Since I alias to the cloudfront distribution, I don't worry about resolvers caching my old cloudfront provided DNS name.  It's worked rather well for me.

Comment: Trying now, but why is deploying in Cloudfront so slow when compared to deploying a EB server.

Comment: @PaulTaylor It's because CloudFront needs to deploy the changes to the hundred or so POPs around the world. Could probably still be faster, mind you... but there's a still a lot more for it to do than one EB deployment.

Answer (score 2):

There's a variation of a joke that says "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think, 'I know, I'll use caching.' Now they have two problems."

Generally speaking, needing invalidation (especially "immediate") invalidation is an antipattern when using a CDN. There are a few ways around this:

- (best) when giving links to content in your distribution, version the links. You said it changes monthly- so maybe /image-2015-04.jpg was last month's image, and now it's /image-2015-05.jpg.
- use Cache-Control headers so the content is reverified every time, or perhaps every hour

Using Route53 for this is sketchy- not only is there a TTL (cache period) with DNS, but not all servers honor short TTLs.

Comment: I think you'll probably right about needing to use cache-control headers or versioning but I was just trying to keep it simple. However there is another scenario that would not solve - code changes. If I need to deploy a new version of my server and thats relies on new css/javascript etc they would all need to be invalidated in CloudFront - what would you do in this situation ?

Comment: Your server presumably links to the static content. In the case of code changes, you use a new unique path to the new content. This is really common- Ruby has an "asset pipeline" that does this automagically. As a simple example- maybe your main.css becomes main-{{git hash}}.css.

Comment: the static content such as css is deployed within the software (i.e its not stored in separate S3 cache) but the point is everything goes through CloudFront so cloudfront would just serve the existing widget.css rather than trying to get a new one form the server. I dont much like the idea of essentially adding versioning to my actual code just to deal with a Cloudfront issue.

Comment: the problem is that it isn't a cloudfront issue, it's how caches (especially CDNs) work.

Comment: Okay I dont want to make code changes just so they work with a CDN then, thats not unreasonable is it ?